# How can I extract the regular expression from a RegularExpressionAttribute?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, reflection, custom-attributes

I have a class like

```
public class Foo
{
    [RegularExpression(@"([A-Za-z0-9\-_ ]+){1,100}")]
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}
```

and for the purpose of unit testing I want to be able to extract out the `"@"([A-Za-z0-9\-_ ]+){1,100}"`.

I know it's something like

```
string expr = typeof(Foo).GetProperty("Bar").....
```

but I don't quite know how to finish it.

Answer (score 1):

```
var property = typeof(Foo).GetProperty("Bar");
var attribute = property.GetCustomAttribute<RegularExpressionAttribute>();
var expr = attribute?.Pattern;
```

Or single statement:

```
var expr = typeof(Foo).GetProperty("Bar")
                      .GetCustomAttribute<RegularExpressionAttribute>()?.Pattern;
```

NOTE: I don't think that you should extract data from property attributes for unit testing. I would either leave property validation for acceptance tests. Or used something like [Validator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validator.aspx) class to actually run validation on your object.